# What is a good lightweight Linux distro for my pc (2x 2.9GHz, 2GB RAM)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have an older PC with windows and I want to install Linux there. I have no experience with these OS by now.

The System
Intel Pentium G850 2.9GHz 2.9 GHz
RAM 2GB

I want to be it lightweight. No Games. Probably just to get familiar with Linux. Maybe a little bit coding and surfing.

I thought about Ubuntu because it is so widely used.
Or elementary os, because in one youtube video it was the most efficient on a low-end PC.

Comment: Sorry, but this sort of question is off topic here since it is just a question of what you prefer. Pretty much _any_ Linux distro will run on the hardware you describe. So sure, try one of the ones that have lightweight GUI environments like Lubuntu or Elementary, both of which are easy for new users as well.

Comment: I'm using Linux Lite (based on Lubuntu) on a very old netbook, it's working great! It was sluggish under Windows 7 without any apps (just by running Windows). Now everything runs fast, even Firefox! For the first time I was able to open 30 tabs without bringing the system to a halt. Besides googling, you can search linux.com or distrowatch.com for reviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/), which is a light version of Ubuntu using a different desktop environment called LXDE.

There are a lot of other Linux distributions that will run fine on old hardware:

- Linux Lite
- LXLE
- Tiny Core